# Boot from mass storage in GRUB2 error

Tags: bootable-media, grub2, write-protect

So I want to install a new system using liveUSB. However the .iso file is avout 5.5GB big and the only thing that can handle such capacity is my SD Card (16 GB, pendrives are only 4 GB). I've made the SD card bootable through uNetbootin software on Windows. However my SD card slot seems not to be connected via USB Bus - computer does not see it in Boot Devices.

So I figured out that I can use my old Samsung Gio (GT-S5660) in Mass Storage mode.

The first problem I encountered with that is that Android software kept upolading its file when I inserted the card into its slot. I could not set the card in write protect mode using the registry (I followed [that tutorial](http://www.ehow.co.uk/how_6528281_remove-write-protection-sd-card.html) and used even a software which was supposed to do that). Both didn't help. But I continued to struggle on. The read-only switch was only on the SD adapter. I had to insert microSD card into the phone. I even managed to get into uNetbootin menu, but it said that there was something wrong with the burned OS. I burned it again and continued to search for the solution.

The switch to mass storage mode in Gio took too many time so I figured out that I can use GRUB2 command line to boot from that. I entered the command line and followed [Ekevoo answer on that tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/349633/boot-from-usb-using-grub), typing:

```
set root=(fd0)
chainloader +1
boot
```

But the GRUB2 then says: *Boot error*

How do I overcome this? If you wish to know what OS I am tryung to install just let me know, but I think it is worthless. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Maybe you should try to use your usb pendrive with a net-install option.  It will be much smaller.

Comment: I've searched for that in the internet (since my VAIO supports it). But I couldn't find any clue - maybe I rushed and leaned over to the mentioned option. Can you help me and give me some valuable link? Thank you.

Comment: Use unetbootin?  Which OS are you hoping for?

Comment: Yosemite Zone and my pendrives are just 4GB. Do I need to burn some special OS onto USB using unetbootin which will somehow manage to connect network drive?

Comment: http://www.macbreaker.com/2014/11/how-to-install-os-x-yosemite-on-your-pc-with-yosemite-zone.html        http://www.macbreaker.com/2012/01/is-your-computer-hackintosh-compatible.html

Comment: *The USB drive must be at least 6 GB in size.* My USB drives are only 4GB. I know how to install Yosemite Zone (done that in VirtualBox). Hardware restricts me and I am looking for a way to bypass those problems. Please read through my post again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26266/discussion-between-dean-spicer-and-kamil-kuczaj).