# Booting from a Windows 8 repair USB using Grub2 command line

Tags: linux, windows-8, grub

I installed a Linux Mint 15 dual-boot alongside Windows 8.1. I no longer needed it, so I followed the instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/141818/how-to-uninstall-a-linux-dual-boot-system-from-your-computer/) for detleting the partitions. I then restarted my computer with the intention of booting a Windows 8.1 repair USB, as created by the RecoveryDrive application in Windows 8.1. For the recovery drive, I created it on a separate computer and did not copy the recovery partition.

After plugging in the USB, the Grub2 command line session started up, as expected because the Linux Mint partition was removed. Unfortunately, [this tutorial](https://superuser.com/questions/349633/boot-from-usb-using-grub) is not working from me. Whenever I enter the `chainloader` command, it gives me the following error:

```
error: invalied EFI file path.
```

My only option for the computer is booting a USB from Grub2. I cannot use a recovery disc because the computer does not have CD drive. If no solution exists to repair Windows 8, I would be OK with losing the current installation and re-installing Windows 8. Losing my data isn't a concerned as a I backed it all up before attempting to remove Linux Mint.

Comment: If it's a UEFI installation (apparently it is), you don't need to "repair" Windows since the EFI binaries (and boot files) of Windows should be still in the EFI System Partition (ESP, unless you deleted it as well). You only need to remove the UEFI boot entry of grub from the NVRAM (with `efibootmgr` in a Mint live CD/USB), and optionally the boot files of grub from the ESP. Make sure you boot the live medium in UEFI mode though.

Comment: Are the steps for booting a live USB containing Mint using Grub2 the same as in the linked SU post?

Comment: You don't use the grub2 on the hard drive to boot a live USB. Just make sure it's made UEFI-bootable and then pick it on your UEFI boot menu. I actually doubt that your grub2 can still boot anything (since I assume it's the RESCUE shell, not the normal shell). It's the same case if you want to boot a Windows recovery or installation USB.

Comment: There is no UEFI boot menu when I start the computer. It immediately opens up the Grub2 RESCUE shell.

Comment: Is it a laptop or some OEM PC? I don't know how I can help you if you cannot get into UEFI setting or its boot menu. (e.g. DEL, F12, F2, F10, ESC...)

Comment: It's a laptop. When I set up the dual-boot with Mint, Grub overwrote the boot menu that came with Windows.

Comment: I see. It can be tricky then. I am not talking about the boot menu of Windows, but that of the UEFI (something like the BIOS boot menu for BIOS system).