# Installing Windows 10 with USB stick from Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub

Hi I'm trying to install windows 10 from a usb drive, I have my USB drive NTFS formatted with the files from the Microsoft site .This is what it's content looks like :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6W2R.png

My USB viewed by Disks My USB viewed by Disks
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mf83.png

My plan was to boot with my USB stick from the grub menu, I found my usb by pressing tab : (hd1,msdos1)

But I try set root (hd1,msdos1) it throw an error saying : wrong efi path

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1l70.png

I already checked these sites : [Boot from USB using GRUB](https://superuser.com/questions/349633/boot-from-usb-using-grub)  https://askubuntu.com/questions/932999/boot-and-install-windows-10-using-grub