# Option to boot from live USB doesn't show up in GRUB menu

Tags: boot

I have a problem with Kubuntu. I can't start the system because I moved the directory bin, and I need to boot from a USB or DVD with an image of Kubuntu to repair it, but in GRUB the option to boot from USB doesn't appear. Can somebody help me?

Comment: i tried that but nothing, my partner said me that appears a options in grub for boot  from USB or DVD

Comment: It won't appear automatically in grub but can try to find it in the grub command line and boot from there. But if you don't see it at all in BIOS, I don't think it will appear in grub either. This question describes how to do it from grub: https://superuser.com/questions/349633/boot-from-usb-using-grub

Comment: When i use "chainloader +1" in the DVD or USB say me "invalid EFI file path"